# Graphics Issue with NVIDIA 980 GTX on Win 10: Pink Static Overlay On Fullscreen Games

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card

I've got an issue where when I run certain games in full screen, there is this horrible pink static looking overlay which I'm unable to get rid of - even if I adjust settings. Only running the game in windowed mode helps. Two example games are Dying Light and Prototype. Dead by Daylight however is a game I play in fullscreen without issue to my awareness.

I've trying putting the card into debug mode, reinstalled the current driver, upgrade to a new version that came out today, all to no avail. Unfortunately, searches for pink static on the internet come up pretty dry results-wise, so I've struggled to find similar cases.

Thought posting here with an actual image may help. Has anyone experienced this and know of a fix?

IMG link: https://ibb.co/ft13Oc

Thanks in advance,

Hugh

Comment: Does it happen at any time, day or night? I was wondering if maybe it's the "Night light" feature going awry. (Action center->All settings->type "night" in the search box.)

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thanks for your help Andrew. See my answer I put below; managed to track the cause.

Comment: Downvoted my question but with no reasoning given in the comment section. Thanks, that's really constructive and will definitely help me produce better questions worthy of upvotes in the future.

Comment: It wasn't me, but some people are reluctant to give reasons because they get unpleasant comments back.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out changing the display I was using the game on to one running through a display port cable rather than a DVI-D fixed the problem. Didn't suspect this as the game ran fine outside of full screen.

I use PCI passthrough in a virtual machine within a Linux libvirtd environment. Not sure if it had anything to do with this, but mentioning it so future searching may turn this up.

Thanks for anyone who looked.